# Visualizando arquivo PDF após obter os bytes

Tags: c#, winforms, stream

Gostaria de Visualizar um arquivo `.PDF` hospedado em um `FTP`.
Consigo obter o `Stream` através dos bytes, mas não consigo criar o arquivo em um navegador.

Segue o código até agora:

```
 private void btnVerFilePdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient request = new WebClient();
        string url = "ftp://nfsaai.com.br@hostip/" + "fileexample.pdf";
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userstr", "passwordstr");


        try
        {        
            byte[] newFileData = request.DownloadData(url);
            string fileString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newFileData);
            Console.WriteLine(fileString); 
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("erro : {0}", error.Message));       
        }       
    }
```

Comment: WindowsForm ou WebForms?

Comment: WindowsForm....

Comment: Nesse caso você vai precisar de um componente para exibir em sua aplicação ou salvar ele localmente e abrir o arquivo

Comment: Entendi @LeandroAngelo achei que pudesse com os bytes pego construir o documento em um navegador.

Comment: Talvez com base64 até consiga

Answer (score -2):

A forma mais simples no `WinForms` é utilizando o componente [`Web Browser`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-windows-forms).

**Exemplo:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //No seu caso pode por direto o caminho do FTP:
        RenderizarPDF(@"C:\CaminhoPDF\MeuDocumento.pdf");
    }

    private void RenderizarPDF(string filePath)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath))
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(@filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Caso você tenha problema com a exibição do PDF diretamente do `FTP` no `WebBrowser` eu sugiro implementar uma funcionalidade que salve o Stream do PDF que você já obteve em uma pasta temporária com um [`Guid`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=netframework-4.7.2) que identifica o arquivo e após a conclusão da leitura você pode apagar o PDF que possui aquele nome.